# Exoplayer's DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource not working

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am implementing a music application. I am using `Exoplayer2`

I am trying to use `DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource` to add & remove items to the playlist dynamically.

Here is my implementation.

```
public void initMusicPlayer(){

        if (songs !=null)
        {

            MediaSource mediaSource;
            ArrayList<MediaSource> sources = new ArrayList<>();

            MusicItem song;
            for (int i=0;i< songs.size();i++)
            {
                song = songs.get(i);
                mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(song.getMusicUrl()));
                sources.add(mediaSource);
            }

            dynamicMediaSource = new DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource();
            dynamicMediaSource.addMediaSources(sources);
            exoPlayer.prepare(dynamicMediaSource,false,false);

            exoPlayer.addListener(this);
            if (currentPlayingSongIndex == -1)
            {
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            }
            else
            {
                exoPlayer.seekTo(currentPlayingSongIndex,0);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        }
    }

public void addItemToPlaylist(MusicItem song,boolean shouldPlay){

        long position = exoPlayer.getContentPosition();
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(song.getMusicUrl()));
        dynamicMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.prepare(dynamicMediaSource,false,false);

        if (shouldPlay)
        {
            exoPlayer.seekTo(currentPlayingSongIndex,0);
        }
        else
        {
            exoPlayer.seekTo(currentPlayingSongIndex,position);
        }
    }
```

But, this implementation is not working. It doesn't play anything.

What's wrong in the above code ?

Also, how to add items dynamically to playlist ? Will the above `addItemToPlaylist` work ?

Comment: What error you got? please post error log..

Comment: Its not giving any error. Immediately its going to `onPlayerStateChanged` with player state `STATE_ENDED`

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I created to play a playlist of mp3 files in Kotlin.
(You can copy paste it in Android Studio and it will be converted to Java if you use Java)

```
private fun mediaPlayerConfiguration() {
    val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
    val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()
    val trackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory)
    val defaultBandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "mediaPlayerSample"), defaultBandwidthMeter)

    val dynamicConcatenatingMediaSource = DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource()

    for (item in myActivity.list) {
        var mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).setExtractorsFactory(extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(item))
        dynamicConcatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
    }

    mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector)
    mPlayer.prepare(dynamicConcatenatingMediaSource)

    mPlayer.playWhenReady = true
}
```